# How to get a posebones global tail position

Tags: python, animation, armature

I need to write a script, which makes sure, that the tip of my armature never gets under the ground, which will be a flat plane. how would i access the global position of the posebones tail?
[image: The bones tail must not be under the ground]

Answer (score 8):

If you have your armature object as `arm`, you can get its n<sup>th</sup> bone’s tail local position (i.e. its pose location in armature’s object space) with `arm.pose.bones[n].tail`, so to get that in world coordinates, just multiply it with the armature’s world matrix: `arm.matrix_world * arm.pose.bones[n].tail`.

Note however it may be simpler (in simple cases) to use a bone constraint like `Floor` or `Limit Position` ones…